# How to achieve local area distortion zoom?

Tags: graphics, regions, generative-art

This work was authored by Victor Vasarely. I wanted to reproduce a similar image effect and colour effect.

[image]

I made a simple attempt to draw out the original background section first.

```
r = Table[Disk[{x, y}, 0.1], {x, 0, 2.9, 0.2}, {y, 0, 2.9, 0.2}] // 
   Flatten;
area1 = CSGRegion[
   "Difference", {Rectangle[{-0.1, -0.1}, {2.9, 2.9}], 
    CSGRegion["Union", r]}, 
   BaseStyle -> RGBColor[61/255, 92/255, 139/255]];
area2 = CSGRegion["Union", 
   Table[Disk[{x, y}, 0.1], {x, 0, 2.9, 0.2}, {y, 0, 2.9, 0.2}] // 
    Flatten, BaseStyle -> White];
image = Graphics[{area1, area2}]
```

[image]

Next, a localised area of zoom distortion was carried out (But this place doesn't handle that well.).

```
center = {0.5, 0.5};
radius = 0.5; scale = 1.3; twist = 0.8; 
transformationFunction = 
  Function[{pt}, 
   Module[{dist, angle, newPt}, dist = EuclideanDistance[pt, center];
    If[dist <= radius, angle = twist (1 - dist/radius);
     newPt = 
      pt + scale (pt - center) (1 - dist/radius)^2 {Cos[angle], 
         Sin[angle]}, newPt = pt];
    newPt]];
distortedImage = 
 ImageForwardTransformation[image, transformationFunction]
```

[image]

All in all, I would expect the 'distorted zoom' effect and the colour distribution to be similar to the original image.

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15065/)

Comment: Especially useful tips, thanks! @J.M.'seventualburnout