# How can we produce sliceforms?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, generative-art

Sliceforms are models made from intersecting sets of planes
which slot together to generate intersecting three-dimensional
surfaces. Here are some of them made by Nadja Vohradsky for the

[university of oxford mathematics-online-exhibition 2020](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/about-us/art-and-oxford-mathematics/oxford-mathematics-online-exhibition-2020/nadya-vohradsky)

[image]

Sliceforms sit happily on the border between art and mathematics, as we can see in this graphic by Victor Vasarely:

[image]

**My request**

I think it is very difficult to reproduce some of the three-dimensional forms (certainly too difficult for me). I would therefore also accept two-dimensional, Vasarely-like solutions.

Comment: The 2D case is too difficult for me. I would like to  know  how to product it. I add `graphics` to the tags.

Comment: No problem - the main question concerns the 3D case

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out [`SliceContourPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceContourPlot3D.html) provides almost everything we need:

```
ClearAll[sliceForm]

SetAttributes[sliceForm, HoldAll]

sliceForm[reg_, f_ : x + y, nx_ : 7, ny_ : 7, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 SliceContourPlot3D[f, 
   {{"XStackedPlanes", nx}, {"YStackedPlanes", ny}}, 
   {x, y, z} ∈ reg, 
   opts, 
   PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface",
   Axes -> False, ContourStyle -> None, 
   Boxed -> False, BoundaryStyle -> None,  
   ImageSize -> Medium, Background -> Black, SphericalRegion -> True]



sliceForm[reg_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := sliceForm[reg, x + y, 7, 7, opts]
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[{sliceForm[#], 
  sliceForm[#, x + y, 10, 10, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], 
  sliceForm[#, x + y, 10, 10, PlotTheme -> None]}, Spacer[5]]& @ Ball[]
```

[image]

Replace `Ball[]` with `Cube[]` to get

[image]

Use `Cone[]` to get

[image]

Use `Cylinder[]` to get

[image]

Use `Pyramid[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}]` to get

[image]

Define a solid region as

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[{x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && z <= Sin[x  y]},
   {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}}];
```

[image]

```
Row[{sliceForm[#], 
    sliceForm[#, x + y, 10, 10, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], 
    sliceForm[#, x + y, 10, 10, PlotTheme -> None]}, Spacer[5]] & @ reg
```

[image]

```
Row[{sliceForm[#, BoxRatios -> Automatic], 
    sliceForm[#, x^2 + y^2, 10, 10, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
      BoxRatios -> Automatic], 
    sliceForm[#, x^2 + y^2, 10, 10, PlotTheme -> None, 
      BoxRatios -> Automatic]}, Spacer[5]] & @ FilledTorus[]
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

```
plot = Plot3D[Sin[x*y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[], Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None];
Graphics3D[
 Cases[Normal@plot, 
  Line[pts_] :> 
   Polygon[Join[{{pts[[1, 1]], pts[[1, 2]], -1}}, 
     pts, {{pts[[-1, 1]], pts[[-1, 2]], -1}}]], -1], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- Apple

```
Clear[plot];
plot = ParametricPlot3D[{(1 + Cos[v]) Cos[u] + .1 Cos[5 u], (1 + 
       Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
    1.5 Sin[v] + .5 Cos[v] - .2 Log[1 - v/π]}, {u, 0, 
    2 π}, {v, -π, π}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, 
   Mesh -> 15, Boxed -> False, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> None];
Graphics3D[{Green, 
  Cases[Normal@plot, Line[pts_] :> Polygon[pts], -1]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- Stanford Bunny

```
Clear[reg];
reg = ResourceData["Stanford Bunny"];
plot = RegionPlot3D[reg, Mesh -> 15, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, 
   PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, Boxed -> False];
Graphics3D[{Green, 
  Cases[Normal@plot, Line[pts_] :> Polygon[pts], -1]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- For the thick surface.(Too slow)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
reg = ResourceData["Stanford Bunny"];
plot = RegionPlot3D[reg, Mesh -> 15, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, 
   PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, Boxed -> False];
Show[Cases[Normal@plot, 
  Line[pts_] :> 
   RegionPlot3D[Polygon[pts], {"Extrusion" -> .002}, 
    BoundaryStyle -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue], -1], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

- For the 2D case, I foud the exellent answer of @Vancheers [How to achieve local area distortion zoom?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/292599/72111)

```
Clear[g, image];
g = Graphics[
  Table[{FaceForm[Darker@Red], Rectangle[{i, j}, {i + 1, j + 1}], 
    FaceForm[], 
    Rectangle[{i, j} + {.1, .1}, {i + 1, j + 1} - {.1, .1}], 
    FaceForm[Black], 
    Triangle[{{i, j} + {.1, .1}, {i, j} + {.1, .9}, {i, 
        j} + {.9, .9}}], FaceForm[White], 
    Triangle[{{i, j} + {.1, .1}, {i, j} + {.9, .1}, {i, 
        j} + {.9, .9}}]}, {i, 1, 20}, {j, 1, 20}]]
image = Image[g];
```

[image]

```
center = {0.5, 0.5};
radius = .5; scale = 2.5; twist = 1;
transformationFunction = 
  Function[{pt}, 
   Module[{dist, angle, newPt}, dist = EuclideanDistance[pt, center];
    If[dist <= radius, angle = twist  (1 - dist/radius);
     newPt = 
      pt + scale  (pt - center)  (1 - dist/radius)^2  {Cos[angle], 
         Sin[angle]}, newPt = pt];
    newPt]];
distortedImage = 
 ImageForwardTransformation[image, transformationFunction]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, cvgmt, your reproduction  is really astonishing in its faithfulness to Vasarely's work.

Answer (score 11):

An attempt, where I have hollowed out the ball. This can save material.

```
hx = Hyperplane[{1, 0, 0}, #] & /@ Range[-5, 5, 2];
hy = Hyperplane[{0, 1, 0}, #] & /@ Range[-5, 5, 2];
hz = Hyperplane[{0, 0, 1}, #] & /@ Range[-5, 5, 2];

RegionDifference[
  RegionIntersection[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 10], #] & /@ hx~Join~hy~Join~hz //
    RegionUnion,
  Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 8]
  ] // DiscretizeRegion
```

---

[image]

---

```
RegionIntersection[Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {4, 4, 8}], #] & /@ 
   hx~Join~hy~Join~hz // RegionUnion // Region
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

We use [`CSGRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CSGRegion.html) to construct a [`CSGRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CSGRegion.html) object using scaled/translated/possibly-rotated versions of `Cube[]` and use it to slice 3D solids:

```
ClearAll[csgSlicer]

Options[csgSlicer] = 
   {"BladeThickness" -> .025,
    "BladePositions" -> Most[Rest@Range[-1, 1, .25]], 
    "RotationAngle" -> 0,
    "Length" -> 2, 
    "Width" -> 2};

csgSlicer[OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{$tr, $dir, $ra, $bt, $bp, $l, $w, $t},
  {$ra, $bt, $bp, $l, $w} = OptionValue @ 
    {"RotationAngle", "BladeThickness", "BladePositions", "Length", "Width"};
  CSGRegion["Union", 
   Join[Map[Rotate[Translate[Scale[Cube[], {$bt, $l, $w}], {#, 0, 0}], 
          $ra, {0, 1, 0}] &] @ $bp, 
        Map[Rotate[Translate[Scale[Cube[], {$l, $bt, $w}], {0, #, 0}], 
          $ra, {1, 0, 0}] &] @ $bp]]]
```

***Examples:***

```
csgSlicer[]
```

[image]

```
csgSlicer["BladeThickness" -> .1]
```

[image]

```
csgSlicer["RotationAngle" -> 45  Degree, 
 BaseStyle -> {EdgeForm[], Specularity[White, 20], Red}]
```

[image]

Using `csgSlicer` to slice 3D solids:

```
{ball, cube, cone, cylinder, dodecahedron, pyramid} = 
 {Ball[], Cube[2], Cone[], Cylinder[], Dodecahedron[], 
  Pyramid[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}]};

Grid[Partition[#, 3] & @
  Map[CSGRegion["Intersection", {ToExpression @ #, csgSlicer[]}, 
      ImageSize -> Medium, PlotLabel -> Style[#, White], 
      Lighting -> "Neutral", Background -> Black, 
      BaseStyle -> {EdgeForm[None], Specularity[White, 20], Orange}] &] @ 
 {"cube", "ball", "cylinder", "cone", "pyramid", "dodecahedron"}, 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Replace `csgSlicer[]` with `csgSlicer["BladeThickness" -> .05, "RotationAngle" -> 60  Degree]` to get

[image]

Replace `csgSlicer[]` with

```
csgSlicer["BladeThickness" -> .01, 
 "BladePositions" -> (Join[#, -#] &@Most@Rest[Subdivide[-1, 1, 9]])]
```

to get

[image]

Replace `"Intersection"` with `"Difference"` and use `csgSlicer["BladeThickness" -> .1,  "Length" -> 10, "Width" -> 10]` to get

[image]